# Lambda assignment via ctor rvalue argument

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Got this ScopeExit class off code-project but it would not build on GCC 4.5.3. Appreciate any help.

```
class ScopeExit : private boost::noncopyable
{
    typedef std::function<void()> func_t;

public:
    ScopeExit(func_t&& f) : func(f) {}
    ~ScopeExit() { func(); }

private:
    // no default ctor
    ScopeExit();

    // Prohibit construction from lvalues.
    ScopeExit(func_t&);

    // Prohibit new/delete.
    void* operator new(size_t);
    void* operator new[](size_t);
    void operator delete(void *);
    void operator delete[](void *);

    const func_t func;
};


ScopeExit exit = [&]() { };
```

gcc 4.5.3 errors:

```
In member function ‘void test()’:
error: conversion from ‘test()::<lambda()>’ to non-scalar type ‘ScopeExit’ requested
```

Edit:

```
ScopeExit exit([&]() { }); // this works
```

Comment: Since this is c++11 code: Why use a `private` constructors/operators to prohibit those? Anything wrong with `ScopeExit(func_t&)=delete;`? Also note that the compiler generated default constructor is disabled since the type has a user defined constructor and that constructing from an lvalue isn't possible, if the constructor onyl accepts rvalues, so neither of those two constructors needs to be explecitely removed. For the `operator new/delete` using `=delete;` should do it.

Comment: I didn't write the code. Like I said, it's from code-project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's copy/move initialization. Your copy c-tor is deleted, move c-tor is deleted too.

n3337 12.8/9

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
> as defaulted if and only if
>
> **— X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,**
>
> **— X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,**
>
> — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
>
> **— X does not have a user-declared destructor, and**
>
> — the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

Have no ideas why first case doesn't work, but this case works fine

```
template<typename T>
ScopeExit(T&& f) : func(std::move(f)) {}
ScopeExit(ScopeExit&& rhs) : func(std::move(rhs.func)) { }]
```

**EDIT.**

When we use `copy-initialization` of variable of class-type only standard and elipsis implicit conversions are used. Conversion from lambda to function pointer or from function pointer to `std::function` is `user-defined conversion` and not used.

n3337 8.5/16

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is the type of the object or reference being
> initialized and the source type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly
> parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
>
> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences
> that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function
> is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is
> chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the
> initialization is ill-formed.

n3337 13.3.1.4/1

> Under the conditions specified in 8.5, as part of a copy-initialization of an object of class type, a user-defined
>    conversion can be invoked to convert an initializer expression to the type of the object being initialized.
> Overload resolution is used to select the user-defined conversion to be invoked. Assuming that “cv1 T” is
> the type of the object being initialized, with T a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> — The converting constructors (12.3.1) of T are candidate functions.
>
> 1. In both cases, the argument list has one argument, which is the initializer expression. [ Note: This argument
>    will be compared against the first parameter of the constructors and against the implicit object parameter
>    of the conversion functions. — end note ]

n3337 13.3.2

> 1. From the set of candidate functions constructed for a given context (13.3.1), a set of viable functions is
> chosen, from which the best function will be selected by comparing argument conversion sequences for the
> best fit (13.3.3). The selection of viable functions considers relationships between arguments and function
> parameters other than the ranking of conversion sequences.
>
> Second, for F to be a viable function, there shall exist for each argument an implicit conversion se-
> quence (13.3.3.1) that converts that argument to the corresponding parameter of F.

n3337 13.3.3.1/4

> However, when considering the argument of a constructor or user-defined conversion function that is a
> candidate by 13.3.1.3 when invoked for the copying/moving of the temporary in the second step of a class
> copy-initialization, by 13.3.1.7 when passing the initializer list as a single argument or when the initializer
> list has exactly one element and a conversion to some class X or reference to (possibly cv-qualified) X is
> considered for the first parameter of a constructor of X, or by 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 in all cases, only
> standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered.

Comment: The first case does not work because of what Matt says in the other answer, no? If no copy constructor is available, copy-initialization won't work.

Comment: Strange how the code compiles on MSVC2010. Most likely MC++ compiler bug.

Comment: @jogojapan if there is `user-declared move c-tor` - code will not work too. With same error. And so, if you use `ScopeExit exit = ScopeExit([]() { });` will works fine.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. I wonder why the first case doesn't work then.

Comment: @jogojapan have no other compilers, but it seems like gcc bug, or something in standard prohibits such usage of lambda to std::function conversion (i.e. lambda to function pointer -> function pointer to std::function).

Answer (score 1):

You've prohibited copy initialization (which is what's happening in the first case) by making the copy constructor private.  But your constructor `ScopeExit(func_t&& f) : func(f) {}` is public, and that's what is getting called in the second (working) declaration.  Playing around with the access control specifications of the two ctors should verify this.

Edit: Wrong terminology as ForEver pointed out, effectively--`ScopeExit(func_t&& f) : func(f) {}` is not a move-constructor.  But this is what is getting called in the second case and that is why it works, and the privacy of the copy-ctor is why the first case doesn't.

Comment: Isn't there a const missing for a copy-ctor?

Comment: @Itjax good call, I didn't think about that, but see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/), either version will work (and disable the default ctor).

Comment: Its `move c-tor` is not public. It's not `user-defined` and we have `user-defined copy c-tor`, so it cannot be declared as defaulted. C-tor, that receives argument of other type, that class is not `move c-tor`.

Comment: @ForEveR Sorry, what are you talking about? `ScopeExit(func_t&& f) : func(f) {}` is a move-ctor, and it's public.

Comment: It's not `move c-tor`. It's c-tor with one argument of type func_t&&, func_t is not ScopeExit, so it cannot be `move c-tor`.

Comment: @ForEveR You're right, I was using the term incorrectly and will edit my answer accordingly.  So then forget about the move-ctor--but the issue is still that `ScopeExit(func_t&& f) : func(f) {}` is public, and that is what is getting called in the second case.